# Enforce max threshold of tracked connections in eBPF

Tags: counter, bpf, ebpf

I have an kprobe ebpf program that tracks a number of active TCP connections. In order to reduce the overhead, I set an upper limit on the number of the TCP connections that can be tracked simultaneously. Thus, I have to maintain a counter in the ebpf program so that when a new connection establishes, the counter is increased if it is below the limit, and when a connection finishes, the counter is decreased. Since the program is reentrant, the manipulation of the counter should be atomic.

I tried bpf_spin_lock. However it cannot be used in the tracing programs (such as kprobe). Also ebpf has few atomic operations. I knew one operation  __sync_fetch_and_add. However it is not enough to implement the logic here.

I found some discussion online https://lists.iovisor.org/g/iovisor-dev/topic/bpf_concurrency/74407447?p=,,,20,0,0,0::recentpostdate%2Fsticky,,,20,2,20,74407447. The discussion is still open without any viable solution.

Is there any readily available solution out there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the goal is only to limit overhead, why not use a per-cpu array to maintain a count per core?

Comment: per-cpu array can only limit the number per cpu. The following situation can occur: cpu A reaches its limit, and the connection is denied whereas cpu B still has free slots. What I need is a global counter.

Comment: If the overhead in question is CPU cycles, then it's a per-core overhead as well, so I don't see the issue with having a per-core threshold. How will you decide what's a good global counter?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let's assume we are using per cpu counters. I imagine the logic will be like:
if (counter > limit) deny; else {accept; counter++;}  
Since the kernel is preemptive, there is a race condition between counter > limit and counter++. This means even if we are using per cpu counters, we still need some atomic operations. What's your thoughts?

Comment: I just came across this in bpf-helpers(7) — Linux manual page. 

u32 bpf_get_smp_processor_id(void)

              Description
                     Get the SMP (symmetric multiprocessing) processor
                     id. Note that all programs run with preemption
                     disabled, which means that the SMP processor id is
                     stable during all the execution of the program.

It says that the preemption is disabled during a BPF program. If that's the case, then I think we are fine here. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes, that is correct for BPF programs that are not "sleepable". And programs are not sleepable unless you explicitly mark them as such when loading.

Comment: One issue with per cpu counter is as follows. In one kprobe I increase the counter when a connection established. and in another kprobe i decrease the counter when the connection finishes. However these two kprobe can be run by different cpu cores. This results in the counter is increased for one cpu and descreased for another cpu. In other words, the counter is not counted correctly. Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: Ah, that's a good point! I assume you must have a hashmap to track the established connections. What if you simply set the max_entries of that hashmap to the global counter value? Then, if a hashmap update fails, it means you've reached the maximum number of connections.

Comment: I think that will work, Thanks.

Comment: Great! I've written down a more detailed answer. Please comment if there's anything I missed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion in comments, we concluded that the best solution is probably to **rely on the map's `max_entries` parameter to enforce a limit on the number of tracked connections**.

With that approach, the BPF program would then look something like:

```c
// Update an existing connection or insert a new one.
res = bpf_map_update_elem(&conntrack, &tuple, &connection, 0);
if (res == -E2BIG) {
    // The map is full. The max. threshold for tracked connections was reached.
} else if (res != 0) {
    // The map update failed for some other reason.
} else {
    // The map update was successful.
}
```

Accessing hash maps in BPF is an atomic operation, so even in case of concurrent accesses, the map will never contain more elements than `max_entries`. Note the access to specific map elements is not atomic however.

---

We discarded per-CPU arrays to maintain per-CPU counters because there's no guarantee the event closing the connection (e.g., TCP FIN) will be processed on the same CPU as the event opening it (e.g., TCP SYN).